# enable scrollbar for the submenu when the windowHeight is smaller than it

Tags: css, reactjs, scroll, height

I have a submenu on position fixed (height 100vh) but when the submenu is bigger than the window height, it doesn't scroll correctly

```css
ul {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: gray;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 424px) {
  ul {
    max-height: calc(100% - 20px);
    overflow-y: scroll;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="App">
  <ul>
    <li>test1</li>
    <li>test2</li>
    <li>test3</li>
    <li>test4</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be my approach:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.App {
  height: 100%;
}

ul {
  min-height: min-content;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: gray;
  text-align: center;
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="App">
  <ul>
    <li>test1</li>
    <li>test2</li>
    <li>test3</li>
    <li>test4</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```